# Quick sorting algorithm states using middle element as pivot

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I need help understanding exactly how the quick sort algorithm works.  I've been watching teaching videos and still fail to really grasp it completely.

I have an unsorted list: 1, 2, 9, 5, 6, 4, 7, 8, 3
And I have to quick sort it using 6 as the pivot.
I need to see the state of the list after each partition procedure.

My main problem is understanding what the order of the elements are before and after the pivot.  So in this case if we made 6 the pivot, I know the numbers 1 - 5 will be before 6 and 7 - 9 will go after that.  But what will the order of the numbers 1 - 5 be and 7 - 9 be in the first partition given my list above?

Here is the partition algorithm that I want to use (bear in my I'm using the middle element as my initial pivot):

1. Determine the pivot, and swap the pivot with the first element of the list.

Suppose that the index smallIndex points to the last element smaller than the pivot.  The index `smallIndex` is initialized to the first element of the list.

2. For the remaining elements in the list (starting at the second element)
   If the current element is smaller than the pivot

   a.  Increment `smallIndex`
   b. Swap the current element with the array element pointed to by `smallIndex`.
3. Swap the first element, that is the pivot, with the array element pointed to by `smallIndex`.

It would be amazing if anyone could show the list after each single little change that occurs to the list in the algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter.

All that matters - all that the partitioning process asserts - is that, after it has been run, there are no values on the left-hand side of the center point that emerges that are greater than the pivot and that there are no values on the right-hand side that are less than the pivot value.

The internal order of the two partitions is then handled in the subsequent recursive calls for each half.

Comment: So would I be safe to say that after the first partition with 6 as the pivot the list would be: 1, 2, 5. 4, 3, 6, 9, 7, 8?

Comment: That could depend somewhat on your specific implementation, but the way I usually code it, the first swap will be 9 and 3, which would put the 9 in the right-most position.

Comment: Ah, so almost like it reads the values from right to left and if they should be moved to the other side of the pivot that get places there?  If that's the case I totally get it now...  In the way that you usually code it, what would the each partition look like up until the the list is completely sorted?

Comment: That would be a bit long for a comment and, like I said, also depends on exactly how you code it. If you augment your question with your implementation and you hypothesis for each iteration I can comment on whether I think your assumptions are correct.